# Bluestacks (HD-StartLauncher.exe) to open through Command Prompt

Tags: android, batch-file, cmd, automation, bluestacks

I want to open Bluestack .exe file through command prompt(Windows) and terminal(Linux/Mac)...I have made a environment(system) variable for the exe file and calling directly start HD-StartLauncher..after this i want to install apk from cmd too..but unfortunately i am not able to install because the Bluestack is not opened properly...My question is how to wait for any .exe file that it is opened properly or not...wait for the .exe and then run my second command..

Please guyz help me out...
Actually why I am doing this...due to automation...I want to open the Bluestack and install the apk through cmd..

And my another question is how to stop ADs in Bluestack...is there any way to get rid of it ? I am using Bluestack 2.2.21

Answer (score 2):

for opening it in **windows** using command line you can use `explorer`:

```
Explorer.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\BlueStacks\HD-StartLauncher.exe"
```

for installing an `apk` you don't need to open `Bluestacks` at all, you can use `HD-ApkHandler.exe`:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\BlueStacks\HD-ApkHandler.exe" "APK File Address"
```

I hope it helps.